# Windows can not find "run.bat" file, from Processing

Tags: windows, batch-file, processing

I am trying to run a bat file from Processing. But the program does not find it even though the bat file is inside the folder of the Processing file.

My code is:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p1;
try {
  p1 = r.exec("cmd /c start run.bat");
}
catch(Exception c) {
}
```

The error that appears when I run Processing is: "Windows can not find "run.bat" file. Make sure the name is spelled correctly and try again."

Can you help me?

Comment: Try running `cmd /k cd` to see what directory you're in.

Comment: Since you are running the start command from cmd you have to specify the full path for run.bat

Comment: Santiago thank you! it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running the start command from cmd instead of directly from Java, you have to specify the full path. You can get the path to your Java project folder with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. If the batch file is in the root of your project folder, your code would look like this:

```
p1 = r.exec("cmd /c start " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "run.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying paths. Unless you have registered `run.bat` in the registry `App Paths` registry key start has no idea where it is.

You have to tell windows where files are.